# Can't find Live Sass Compiler on Visual Studio on Mac OS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, sass

I'm learning to use Visual Code, and specifically I try to compile my SASS code in CSS code.
I watched several tutorials, and tried to find the extension "Live Sass Compiler", which is supposed to be the best one. But it doesn't appear in the list of the extensions, either in the list of NuGets.
I can find other Sass compilers on NuGets, but I don't know which one I should use on Mac, or how to use them.
Thanks in advance for your help ! Aurélie

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code? The two are very different programs

Comment: The Visual Studio Code Sass compiler is known for being buggy, I recommend avoiding it, you're better off installing Sass via Chocolatey or Homebrew and compiling via command line. [Link for install info here](https://sass-lang.com/install)